# Python: How to find same value in lists and group them in a new list?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have several lists in a list like this:

```
data_list = [ ['W_921', 'OSA15', 'name1', 'name2'], 
              ['W_818', 'OSA15', 'name1', 'name2'], 
              ['W_936', 'LSG2', 'name4', 'name5'], 
              ['W_936', 'OSA15', 'name1', 'name2'], 
              ['W_703', 'EB2', 'name6', 'name7'] ]
```

What I need is to group on the second element of the lists and create a new list like this:

```
grouped_data_list = [ ['OSA15', 'name1', 'name2', 'W_921, W_818, W_936'], 
                     ['LSG2', 'name4', 'name5', 'W_936'], 
                     ['EB2', 'name6', 'name7', 'W_703'] ]
```

Should I better work with dictionaries to achieve this? I had a look at the itertools but could not find a way to get to my desired result.

Comment: What is the value of `W_921`, ...etc? Where does the string `"W_921"` come from? Do you want to record the name of variables?

Comment: Sorry, these are all strings... I corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `pandas`, then using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`, you can achieve this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
>>> ( df.groupby(list(df.columns[1:]), sort=False)
        .agg(', '.join).reset_index().to_numpy().tolist() )

[['OSA15', 'name1', 'name2', 'W_921, W_818, W_936'],
 ['LSG2', 'name4', 'name5', 'W_936'],
 ['EB2', 'name6', 'name7', 'W_703']]
```

Comment: I could probably use pandas. I just installed it but unfortunately I'm getting an error when trying your suggestion. It says: 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @vanchy then it's an older version, use `values.tolist()` instead of `to_numpy().tolist()`